# How can I create an array of the directory contents in Dropbox with PHP

Tags: php, curl, dropbox, dropbox-api

I need to create an array of the directory contents in Dropbox with PHP and save it in a variable. Any thoughts?

Edit:
With this I mean from a web server, not locally.

Comment: dropbox folder is like any other folder on your system so you can use standard ways of directory listing/searching in `php`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I want do do this from a web server. Not locally.

Comment: then edit your question - it's more likely to be read than a comment

Comment: Thank you. Did just that. Better now, or should I specify even more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to be using the Dropbox API, there's a [PHP library for it](http://code.google.com/p/dropbox-php/).

Specifically, you'll need [the getMetaData function](http://code.google.com/p/dropbox-php/source/browse/Dropbox/API.php#272).

```
$files_in_directory = $DropboxObject->getMetaData ("directory/you/want", true);
```

Comment: Were on the right track here. But I've tried to use the dropbox-php before. I don't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

This should help

```
function getDirOptions($path) {
    $back = "";
    if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
        while (false !== ($res = readdir($handle))) {
            $options.="<OPTION VALUE='$res'>$res</OPTION>";
        }
        closedir($handle);

    }
    $back = "<SELECT NAME='dir'>$options</SELECT>";
    return $back;
}
```

Comment: That will only work for local files. I need to have a script that can list the contents of an external directory.

Comment: pass the directory path to this function and it will return the dropdown with the directory's content